# What is the sixth Martin quadruple $\sqrt[n]{x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k+x_4^k} =\text{Integer}$ for $k=1,2,3$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, computational-mathematics

Define a *Martin quadruple* {*a,b,c,d*} as a solution in non-zero integers to the system,

$a+b+c+d = x^2$

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = y^2$

$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 = z^3$

It can be shown that there are an infinite number of solutions. However, the smallest five that are *positive* and *6th-power primitive* (no common factor that is a 6th power, re *cyclochaotic*'s comment below) have the curious linear sums as [*smooth numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number),

$\begin{aligned}
&10 + 13 + 14 + 44 = 9^2 = 3^4\\
&54 + 109 + 202 + 260 = 25^2 = 5^4\\
&102 + 130 + 234 + 318 = 28^2 = 2^4\cdot7^2\\
&198 + 630 + 1594 + 1674 = 64^2 = 2^{12}\\
&570 + 742 + 1094 + 1690 = 64^2 = 2^{12}\end{aligned}$

found by James Allen and Seiji Tomita.  Of course, the squares and the cubes of the addends also add up to a square and cube, respectively.

*What is the sixth such quadruple?*

Comment: References to previous work?

Comment: How do the last three qualify as primitive? $1\neq \gcd (102,130,234,318)=\gcd (198,630,1594,1674)=\gcd (570,742,1094,1690)=2$

Comment: Oops, I meant "6th-power primitive", or the terms do not have a 6th power $u^6$ where $u\ne1$ in common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sixth *primitive positive* one is
$$
\{a,b,c,d\}=\{1630,2594, 3562, 3878 \}.
$$

$$
1630+2594+3562+3878=108^2=2^4 3^6;
$$
$$
1630^2+2594^2+3562^2+3878^2=6092^2;
$$
$$
1630^3+2594^3+3562^3+3878^3=5004^3.
$$

---

*(update)*

The $7$th such quadruple is 
$$
\{a,b,c,d\}=\{259, 1307, 3485, 9349 \}.
$$

$$
259+1307+3485+9349=120^2=2^6 3^2 5^2;
$$
$$
259^2+1307^2+3485^2+9349^2=10066^2;
$$
$$
259^3+1307^3+3485^3+9349^3=9516^3.
$$

Comment: Oleg567: Thanks for answering this old question. Now why I am not surprised that its linear sum $2^4 3^6$ are powers of small primes? _What_ is it with these quadruples?

Comment: Tito: hmm, I have no intuition why linear sums are powers of small primes. 7th quadruple has product of 3 smallest primes.

Comment: The phenomenon does not extend to,$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = y^2$$ $$a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4 = z^4$$ the smallest solution of which is $a,b,c,d = 15935,\,27022,\, 57910,\, 59260$ (See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1216667/4781).) The linear sum is _not_ a smooth number.

Comment: Can you answer one question of this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203923/)? It is similar, but focuses only on $k=2,3$.